# Trying to run a console log on php file storing json but callback error and 404 (not found)

Tags: javascript, php, html

Working with trying to learn json and ajax and how they interoperate with html and javascript
I have a php with json data inside
I am trying to get the json data formatted into the html page but I keep getting error that "callback is not a function" 
I am running the php and html files on my MAMP server to simulate a api feed
I will share my html and js files

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="run2.js"></script>
<title>Ajax Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1 class="title">Todays Weather Forecast</h1>
<p class="sub">Click the button the check the local weather.</p>

<button class="demo-centered" type="button" onclick="loadPhp()">Check Weather</button><br><br>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>

</html>

 var loadPhp = function(url, callback) {
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('GET', url, true);
 xhr.responseType = 'json';
 xhr.onload = function () {
    var status = xhr.status;
    if (status == 200) {
        callback(null, xhr.response);

    } else {
        callback(status);
    }
 };
  xhr.send();
 };

loadPhp('demo.php', function (err, data) {
if (err != null) {
    alert('Something went wrong: ' + err);
} else {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (x in data[i]) {
            console.log(data[i][x]);
        }
    }
 }
});

PHP just in case
{"coord":{"lon":-116.8,"lat":33.03},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":293.73,"feels_like":289.89,"temp_min":289.26,"temp_max":295.93,"pressure":1016,"humidity":52},"visibility":16093,"wind":{"speed":5.7,"deg":260},"clouds":{"all":40},"dt":1589408840,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5686,"country":"US","sunrise":1589374130,"sunset":1589423903},"timezone":-25200,"id":5391832,"name":"San Diego County","cod":200}
```

Comment: How would I go about getting something like just the temp and the description only on an html page?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a javascript function called callback to do what the you want the callback to do.